# pyodbc fails without error

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

Would be interested if someone can point me in the right direction.

I have one very long stored proc (that also contains calls to other stored procs within it) that updates various tables.

If I run the stored proc in management studio it runs fine. If I call it from pyodbc then:

1. It runs for the same amount of time that it usually does
2. I get no errors
3. None of the tables its meant to update get updated

I run pyodbc to execute stored procedures all the time and have no problems - I know there is nothing wrong with my connections or calls as if I substitute a shorter stored proc into the python code in the same place it works fine.

The stored proc does generate a few "Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation" messages, I thought that these might be causing problems but whenever I try to SET ANSI_WARNINGS { ON | OFF } either inside the stored proc or outside the stored proc I got a pyodbc.ProgrammingError

Any guesses as to the problem?

```
Python 3.4 (have the same problem in 2.7), MSSQL, Windows 7
```

UPDATED:

```
import pyodbc as p

def getconn():
    server='insertsqlservername'
    dbase='insertdbasename'
    connStr=('Driver={SQL Server};SERVER=' +
              server + ';DATABASE=' + dbase + ';' +
              'trusted=1')
    conn = p.connect(connStr)
    return conn

def runSQL():
    conn=getconn()
    cursor=conn.cursor()

    try:
        cursor.execute('exec InsertStoredProcName')
        conn.commit()
    except:
        print('sys.exc_info()[0])

    cursor.close()
    conn.close()
```

Just to be 100% on the problem there seem to be two components:

- Python Code: If I use the same python code but change the stored proc to a different one then the python code works
- SQL Code: The "problem" stored proc works in T-SQL, but not when run in pyodbc

It seems to be something about the combination of the two.

Comment: could you provide your code without your code we can not say anything

Comment: And if you need a guess i belive that you did not commit your update in pyodbc

Comment: Thanks Vignesh, definitely committed the transaction - have added the python code above. For the SQL its well over 1,000 lines long. Key elements that I can see with the SQL are that the problem stored proc: a) contains other stored procs that it calls b) creates temp tables c) updates other tables d) generates a number of "Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation" messages that I can't work out how to turn off and use pyodbc at the same time

Comment: Shouldn't there be a extra `'` in the print statement

Comment: Try `a=cursor.fetchall() for c in a: print c` to get the output of your stored procedure

Comment: the cursor.fetchall() actually generates an error - previous SQL was not a query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you include your pyodbc connection string? It sounds like you're not setting autocommit when you connect, which causes the changes you make to be rolled back when the connection is closed. You have two options, if this is the case. First, you can set autocommit to be on when you connect:

```
conn = pyodbc.connect(connection_str, autocommit=True)
```

Or, before you close the connection:

```
conn.commit()
```

Comment: Thanks Flipper, added the code above - definitely committing transaction and if I substitute the stored proc name then the python code works fine.

Comment: Thanks this saved me big time!