# TRUNCATE TABLE not working in Pyodbc

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, python-3.x, pyodbc

```
import pyodbc

con=pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};Server=New;Database=Countrydatabase;Trusted_connection=yes')
cur=con.cursor()
cur.execute("TRUNCATE Countrydatabase..region")   
con.close()
```

I am trying to truncate a table using the pyodbc module. But it keeps throwing an error.

> Traceback (most recent call last): File
>   "C:/Users/sean/Desktop/script.py", line 6, in 
>   cur.execute("TRUNCATE Countrydatabase..region")
>   pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL
>   Server  Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'Countrydatabase'.
>   (102) (SQLExecDirectW)")

Same code works fine when I use "SELECT" statement.

Answer (score 6):

My issue with Truncate not working appears to be the Auto Commit setting wasn't working after I explicitly called `con.close()`:

`con = pyodbc.connect("conn", autocommit=True)`

Or you can explicitly perform commits before closing:

`con.commit()`

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31611279/845584

Answer (score 5):

As the error messages shows, your SQL is incorrect.

It should be:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE region
```

(You don't need to specify the database, since you are connected to Countrydatabase already.)

Comment: Thanks. But it does not affect the table.the table remains the same with all the entries.

Comment: @vv4 : `TRUNCATE TABLE Countrydatabase..region` works ?

Comment: @vv4 this is not related to the problem posted in your question. This answer should solve it. If you still have data in your table is because there are related records that need to be deleted first or because the user does not have enough permissions but as I wrote, this is not related to your specific question.

Answer (score 2):

PeterX's comment above was my solution. I set autocommit=True when instantiating the command and my tables started to be truncated.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to prefix it with dbo. something like: dbo.tablename

I was playing around with it today and had the same issue and adding the dbo part worked :-)